# How to select basic salary of each employee in every month during a financial period?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table

Financial Year  : 2014-April-01  - 2015-March-01

```
Employee   Effective Date     Basic Salary
Freddy       2012-Apr-01         1000
Ann          2013-Apr-01          900
John         2014-Mar-01         1000
Ann          2014-Aug-01         1200
John         2014-Oct-01         1500
Freddy       2014-Oct-01         2000
John         2015-Jan-01         3000
Freddy       2015-Mar-01         2500
```

Output :

Financial Year : 2014-April-01  - 2015-March-01

```
  Name | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar
Freddy  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2000  2000  2000  2000  2000  2500
Ann      900   900   900   900  1200  1200  1200  1200  1200  1200  1200  1200
John    1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1500  1500  1500  3000  3000  3000
```

Answer (score 3):

I first create your data:

```
declare @table table(Employee varchar(10), Effective_Date date, Basic_Salary int);
Insert into @table(Employee, Effective_Date, Basic_Salary) values
('Freddy', '2012-April-01', 1000)
, ('Ann', '2013-April-01', 900)
, ('John', '2014-Mar-01', 1000)
, ('Ann', '2014-Aug-01', 1200)
, ('John', '2014-Oct-01', 1500)
, ('Freddy', '2014-Oct-01', 2000)
, ('John', '2015-Jan-01', 3000)
, ('Freddy', '2015-Mar-01', 2500);
```

This is the start of your financial year:

```
Declare @startDate date = '2014-April-01';
```

Main query:

```
With finYears(finY) as (
    Select DATEADD(month, n, @startDAte) From (values(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) as x(n)
)
Select * From (
    Select e.Employee, name = Left(DATENAME(month, f.finY), 3), t.Basic_Salary 
    From finYears f
    Cross Join (Select distinct Employee From @table) as e
    Cross Apply (Select MAX(Effective_Date) From @table x Where x.Effective_Date <= f.finY and x.Employee = e.Employee) mx(maxYear)
    Inner Join @table t on t.Employee = e.Employee and t.Effective_Date = mx.maxYear
) as p
Pivot(
    sum(Basic_Salary)
    for name in ([Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar])
) as piv
```

- finYears CTE is use to create consecutive month from 2014-April-01 to 2015-March-01
- it first select each 12 months from finYears and Cross Join with each employee in order to have 12 month for each employee
- it then look for the closest date in the salary table for each date in finYear
- it finally join it with the salary table in order to get the salary for each month

Once the data is ready with a salary for each month for each employee, it pivots the table for the 12 months.

Output:

```
Employee    Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec     Jan     Feb     Mar
Ann         900     900     900     900     1200    1200    1200    1200    1200    1200    1200    1200
Freddy      1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2500
John        1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    1500    1500    1500    3000    3000    3000
```